# Python Program to tell amount of image files that will fit on a disk/flash drive

Tags: python, image, file

Someone on here asked a question similar to this, but it got quickly downvoted and closed due to the newbiness of it's nature. So I decided to answer it myself, and for others who want to know how to make this nifty program, because it isn't really such a bad idea. So here goes nothing!

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code. Please do not bother fixing your question to make its purpose clearer: you are basically providing code to divide user input by 25, and this is too basic a problem for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I took a couple of pictures (JPEG FORMAT) (With a software I developed myself :3) and got their file sizes, and they averaged out at about 25kb. So then to get the amount of pictures on a disk, you take it's available space in kilobytes, and divide it by 25 (Or larger for different file types, not really sure).

For the program, I asked the user to enter amount of gigs available, and then the program multiplies it by 1048576 (Kbs in a Gig) and stores it as a value, then multiplies it by 25.

So, here is the wonderful code (Hopefully the comments kinda explain what is going on, I am not to great at this):

```
#Main Loop
while True:
    #Set number of Gigs
    totstor=raw_input("Enter the amount of storage on the desired disk (In gb): ")
    #Just in case you get bored
    if totstor=='quit':
        break
    try:
        #Do the math
        gigs=int(totstor)
        gigs=round(gigs)
        kilos=gigs*1048576
        kilos=kilos/25
        kilos=round(kilos)
        kilos=str(kilos)
        kilos=kilos.strip('.0')
        print 'Space for about '+kilos+' standard jpg image files available'
    #If an error occurs, let em' know
    except:
        print 'Invalid Number!'
        print '\n'
    print '\n'
#Bye
quit()
```

Anyone who got any help out of this, leave some feedback. Or just tell me how horrendous my code is xD.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to tell you your code is horrendous. But you could simplify it.

Everything in the `try` routine could be replaced by a single line:

`print 'Space for about', int(totstor*1048576/25), 'standard jpg image files available'`

In other words you can print the result of the calculation directly. Let `int()` take care of rounding, getting rid of ".0", etc., and rely on the fact that you can print integers (and most other data types) directly without converting them to a string. You simply chain together the items you need in the output using commas. (There are other ways of getting numbers into the desired output text, but this is simplest).

Comment: Wow, never knew that! Makes my code look like a mammoth compared to that! Upvoted!